# Mock next/link with Jest in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

How to mock the Link component from "next/link" with jest in Next JS and check the redirect path after a click on a link element?

Here an example component with a test:

```js
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/login">
        <span>Click here</span>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
describe("Nav", () => {
  it("redirects correctly", async () => {
  render(<Nav />)

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Click here"));

  // check if redirect to href prop works as expected

  });
});
```

Comment: what is result of your test: fails or passes? Question how to mock Link is good. But to simulate click on Link you need to click on link and not `Click here` because it is `span` element. You need to get link via `getByRole('link')`, or, if that fails, with `getByText("Click here").closest('link')`, or `getByText("Click here").parent()`

Comment: try `expect(screen.getByText('Click here').closest('link')).toHaveAttribute('href', 'https://myUrl')`

Comment: Thanks, this passes:
expect(screen.getByText("Click here")).toHaveAttribute("href", "/");

But I have no chance to check if the Link was called properly after the fireEvent.click call as the previous example only tests if the element is rendered or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Link was called"? You seem to be testing the framework: if you test that the "Click here" text matches a Link with the right "href", it seems to me that you are done, as you should trust the Link component to handle the redirection

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem Fabio? I'm struggling to fix it right now, can`t test if the Link was actually called.

Answer (score 2):

You may wrap your test with RouterContext provider and pass the mock router as a value

```
import createMockRouter from 'src/test-utils/createMockRouter';
import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

describe("Nav", () => {

let router = createMockRouter({});

 it("redirects correctly", async () => {
  render(
   <RouterContext.Provider value={router}>
     <Nav />
   </RouterContext.Provider>)

   waitFor(() => {
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Click here"));
    expect(router.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');
   });

  });
 });
```

And create a createMockRouter utility in your utils like this.

```
import { NextRouter } from 'next/router';

const createMockRouter = (router: Partial<NextRouter>): NextRouter => {
 return {
   basePath: '',
   pathname: '/',
   route: '/',
   query: {},
   asPath: '/',
   back: jest.fn(),
   beforePopState: jest.fn(),
   prefetch: jest.fn(),
   push: jest.fn(),
   reload: jest.fn(),
   replace: jest.fn(),
   events: {
     on: jest.fn(),
     off: jest.fn(),
     emit: jest.fn(),
   },
   isFallback: false,
   isLocaleDomain: false,
   isReady: true,
   defaultLocale: 'en',
   domainLocales: [],
   isPreview: false,
   ...router,
 };
};
export default createMockRouter;
```

Comment: i did this but i got this error in Link component https://i.imgur.com/3KvGxeM.png

Comment: @markokraljevic, I just ran into this myself as well. It's the `prefetch` that is failing. So change the above code to be `prefetch: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true)`

That cleared the error for me. Took me waaaaay longer than I'd like to admit to figure this out...

Comment: @ThePuzzleMaster yes, i solved it same way, need to return promise instead of undefined `prefetch: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),`

Comment: The test inside waitFor is never callled